# ArcPy Append or Merge Outputs Empty

Tags: arcpy, append

I'm trying to merge or append layers with identical schemas. When I run the append arcpy function in a stand alone script (only the arcpy tool) it works but when I put it my complete script, the script completes but the output from the tool is empty.

I've tried using shapefiles, converting them to feature layers, and using the append and merge tool (both have the same output).

I'm not sure how to get around this and can't seem to find what could be causing this.

Comment: are you using the NO_TEST schema matching setting?

Comment: Are you using Select Layer by Attributes/Location? It's possible you have an empty selection (0 selected) in the layer... try to Select Layer by Attributes with CLEAR_SELECTION before append/merge. Can you post your complete script, or at least the few lines before the merge/append?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user pleas take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of your arcpy code so that we can see what you've actually tried and possibly see what the problem is.  If you are getting error messages please also include those in your question.